# Creating a Debian package for a Qt application built using CMake

Tags: deb, qt, packaging, cmake

I would like to create a .deb installation package for a GUI based Qt5 application.  Most of the links available for this problem are pretty old, so I'm curious if there are more up-to-date solutions for this.  I have attempted many different things in the past.  Ideally whatever packaging tool is used would automatically pull in the required libraries and solve some of the more pesky `platforms` issues with arranging a Qt installation.

I did end up developing a homebrew solution, using a small Qt program to locate Qt libraries and then a series of scripts to package and unpackage, as well as auto-generate things like `.desktop` files.  I am worried that I'm reinventing the wheel and something already exists which fulfills most of these requests (i.e. finds all required dynamic libraries and packages them).

I've tried CQTdeployer, which never ended up working.  `linuxqtdeploy` has a pretty crazy requirement to build on Ubuntu 14.04, which is something that I view as unnecessary for my purposes (e.g. where I control the target systems).  I've tried CpackIFW, but while CpackIFW creates an install script and tarball, it does not incorporate the necessary libraries/platforms to run the program.

I feel like I'm missing something pretty major here, and I would hate to reinvent the wheel in creating a working, simple, packaging system for Linux machines.  Any tips are must appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: Given the packaging was created in the 1990s and is still used today, very little has changed so documentation doesn't really change... Refer https://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/  (though other guides exist, and I tend to also read the Debian guides too as it's usually written by a different person but is describing the exact same procedure..)   FYI:  I'm involved with Lubuntu which only semi-recently switched to using LXQt/Qt5  (*5 releases thus far*) so our documentation isn't what I'd consider old, but we'll still refer you to guides like I've just done often...

Comment: It is interesting to me that in all this time a complete solution which packages things in a more automated fashion has not been developed.  Let's say I'm developing only for the Linux platform (at the moment) and I'm using Qt.  My development system matches my target system.  Why should a packaging software not know to grab the necessary files for distribution automatically without me having to manually specify dependencies each time?

Comment: Don't forget most of us only build test packages on our systems and deal with source code only. We upload source code (patches) and remote systems package & thru CI actually build and start testing for us... Our own systems aren't building the packages (infrastructure we cannot control does that so we cannot be accused of hiding malware, tampering builds etc)

Comment: Is this to say that in most cases the build pipeline beyond source code is out of your hands?  My experience has been with smaller companies and embedded systems where I control everything from source code to deployment.  Therefore the end product is wholly within a domain that I specify.   I can understand how the broader issue is a more general one and thus, my unique circumstance may not have a preestablished fix.

Comment: @AlexBaum Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Could you share `debian/rules` and `debian/control`?

Answer (score 0):

This is works for me.

```bash
sudo snap install cqtdeployer
sudo snap connect cqtdeployer:process-control
sudo snap connect cqtdeployer:removable-media
sudo snap connect cqtdeployer:system-backup
```

```bash
cqtdeployer -bin myApp -qmake myQtDir/qmake deb
```

**Updated:**

See the "CQtDeployer quick guide [page](https://quasarapp.ddns.net:3031/docs/QuasarApp/CQtDeployer/latest/md_md_en_QuickGuide.html)" to learn more

Comment: The question asks about CMake as the build tools and your answer is about qmake, I suppose?

Comment: no, this way independent of the build system.
qmake - it's just deprecated name of option - probably will be replaced in the future